# Redirect users with no CP permissions automatically

Tags: craft4

I have some user groups defined with their specific rules.
A normal user or visitor is of course not allowed to access the admin dashboard.
When I'm logged in as a user with no permissions to access the dashboard, I retrieve an error page from yii which says I'm not authorized to visit this page, what I want.

But instead of seeing this page, I want to be redirected immediately to the homepage with a flash message.

Where can I program this? I'm not sure if this is twig related or module related..

Anyone that can help me out?

Comment: not sure, but are you probably looking for this? https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/general.html#postloginredirect

Comment: Not exactly.. when you would type the url for the admin panel, it should redirect you if you don't have the permissions so that is not a postloginredirect

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it working by changing the function that causes the exception template to trigger.

```
    public function requirePermission(string $permissionName): void
    {
        if (!Craft::$app->getUser()->checkPermission($permissionName)) {
            // throw new ForbiddenHttpException('User is not authorized to perform this action.');
            $default = Craft::t('app','You are not allowed to visit this page');
            Craft::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', Craft::t('app', $default));
            $this->goHome();
        } 
    }
```

By adding a craft sessions flash message and redirect to the home url, I've achieved what I want.

Comment: For the record, it sounds like you edited a core Craft file, which is a bad idea for all sorts of reasons so I'd highly discourage this.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a 403 template (403.twig) that contains content that prompts the user to go login or return to the homepage. Not exactly what you asked for, but its an easy built-in solution to the UX issue.

Comment: Meanwhile, I achieved by rewriting the base craft controller

Comment: @cherrykoda This is a good idea, but [error templates](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/routing.html#error-templates) are only rendered for front end (i.e non-CP) requests, so this wouldn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @StefVerniers Consider adding your solution as an answer; could be helpful to others in the future!

Comment: Ah, apologies. I thought the 403 template appeared for CP URLs as well.